# Better way of finding results within the radius (Geo)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using a query similar to:

```
$distance = "st_distance_sphere(Point({$lat}, {$lon}), Point({$lat}, {$lon})) * 0.000621371192";

$query = "SELECT table.*, {$distance} as distance
WHERE {$distance} < 10 
   AND postcode IN ( 'XX12 3XX', 'XX12 3XX', 'XX12 3XX' )
ORDER BY distance asc
LIMIT 100";
```

The problem kicks in when postcodes contain 100k+ records, this is when the query will take considerable time to return results.

Is there a way of speeding this query up?

Some of the things that I was considering are:

1. turning lat and long into a POINT data type. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-type-overview.html
2. just like with point one but using Elastic Search https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-queries.html

Comment: [_This_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) scales well for the "find nearest" problem.  I'm experimenting with zorder; it is looking similarly performant (and similarly complex).

Comment: @RickJames this exactly what I wanted to avoid :), 90 partitions would be a nightmare to have but seems like the only option! Currently, we are trying to sort results by name, which is a pain, and I am considering to apply the find nearest approach that you have outlined in the link. Have you tried Elastic Search to solve a similar problem? I am considering trying Geo features out on a smaller set of data, 100k-500k records, to see if Elastic performs any better.

Comment: Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31565423/1968909

Comment: @user3402600 - please report back on your findings with Elastic.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena - That is sort of like Z-ordering.  There is also a 'standard' numbering for all of Britain wherein the lat & lng are combined into a single number.  The first few digits give you a general area; as you include more digits, you zoom in tighter.  (Sorry I forget the name of it.  But, again, it is a variant of Zordering.)